# How to count the number of chlamydomonas cells in a image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to count the number of chlamydomonas cells in a image. I have two different kind of images: Bright field images i.e, normal light microscope images and dark field images i.e, Fluoroscence microscopy images using FITC filter. I want to count all cells in bright field and only the fluroscent ones in dark field.

This is for Bright Field

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
import skimage.io as io
# Load the image
img_path = 'C:/Users/m_jen/Downloads/Sem 8/Sen lab project/MJ/input_images/0uMCr002.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)


# Threshold the image
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Minimum and maximum circularity values to consider
min_circularity = 0.4
max_circularity = 1.0

# Minimum and maximum cell size in pixels
min_area = 400
max_area = 10000

# Filter contours based on circularity and size
filtered_contours = []
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if  (min_area <= area <= max_area):
        filtered_contours.append(cnt)

# Draw contours
img_contours = cv2.drawContours(image.copy(), filtered_contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Display the image
cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
res_img_contours = cv2.resize(img_contours, (1280, 720))
cv2.imshow('Contours', res_img_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the number of cells
print(f"Number of cells: {len(filtered_contours)}")
```

I wanted to use circularity as a cutoff but for some reason my perimeter is coming 0 and when i am using a if else block, my system just crashes running the code.
enter image description here

[image: Dark Field]

[image: Bright Field]

Comment: Could you edit your question and add examples of the results you are expecting please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.
Just modified a little the code

1. gray->bgr before drawing countours
2. Added a circularity measurement to filter the items in `filtered_contours`.
3. Added a little median blur before processing.

The function `detect_chlamydomonas` works on both types of images.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from math import pi


def detect_chlamydomonas(image_path, is_dark=False):
    # Load the image
    bgr_image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    gray_image = None
    
    if is_dark is True:
        _, gray_image = cv.threshold(bgr_image, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    else:
        _, gray_image = cv.threshold(bgr_image, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
        
    if gray_image is not None:
        gray_image = cv.medianBlur(gray_image, 5)
        contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(gray_image, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        
        # Minimum and maximum circularity values to consider
        min_circularity = 0.4
        max_circularity = 1.0
        
        # Minimum and maximum cell size in pixels
        min_area = 100
        max_area = 10000
        
        # Filter contours based on circularity and size
        filtered_contours = []
        
        for cnt in contours:
            area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
        
            if min_area <= area <= max_area:
                filtered_contours.append(cnt)
                
        # Adding circularity filtering
        # Circularity = (4 * pi * area) / (perimeter**2)
        # You calculate the area from the filtered_contours item,
        # Then the perimeter. It gives you a score between 0 (not a circle) and 1 (definitely a circle).
        # You use min_circularity and max_circularity to filter the contours.
        final_countours = []
        
        for contour_item in filtered_contours:
            perimeter = cv.arcLength(contour_item, True)
            area = cv.contourArea(contour_item)
            circularity = (4 * pi * area) / (perimeter**2)
            
            if min_circularity <= circularity <= max_circularity:
                final_countours.append(contour_item)
        
        # Draw contours
        bgr_image = cv.cvtColor(gray_image, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv.drawContours(bgr_image, final_countours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        # Display the image
        res_img_contours = cv.resize(bgr_image, (1280, 720))
        cv.imshow('Contours', res_img_contours)
        cv.waitKey(0)
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        
        # Print the number of cells
        print(f"Number of cells: {len(final_countours)}")
    
    
img_dark_path = "./dark_image.jpg"
img_bright_path = "./bright_image.jpg"

detect_chlamydomonas(img_dark_path, is_dark=True)
detect_chlamydomonas(img_bright_path, is_dark=False)
```

Here are the results:

[image: Dark Image Results]

[image: Bright Image Results]

Then just adjust your parameters for circularity and area filtering.